# How to access windows Active Directory anonymously?

Tags: java, ldap, jndi

In my Java web (JBoss) application, I need to get data from Active Directory. Basically, I know the employee's userID (windows login ID), and I need to know his/her office phone number. I think the only place that contains employee's phone # is Windows Active Directory. So I tried some sample java code and try to get access to Active Directory. Here is a sample code (http://myjeeva.com/querying-active-directory-using-java.html)

```
public ActiveDirectory(String username, String password, String domainController) {
    properties = new Properties();        
 
    properties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
    properties.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "LDAP://" + domainController);
    properties.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, username + "@" + domainController);
    properties.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);
 
    // initializing active directory LDAP connection
    try {
        dirContext = new InitialDirContext(properties);
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        LOG.severe(e.getMessage());
    }
 
    // default domain base for search
    domainBase = getDomainBase(domainController);
 
    // initializing search controls
    searchCtls = new SearchControls();
    searchCtls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
    searchCtls.setReturningAttributes(returnAttributes);
}
```

We can see that I need to have user name and password in order to query user's data in active directory, but it is not possible for me to get all user's password. I also tried to set "password" to "none" which tried to use anonymous access, but it does not work.
Does anybody know if it's possible to access Active directory anonymously? I was told in asp.net, it is possible to access active directory without providing user id and password. I am wondering it should be working in Java as well. I appreciate any help or examples. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

1. AFAIK nowadays it's pretty uncommon to allow an anonymous login to an ldap server
2. Ask the admin of the Active Directory server, if 1) is (partially) allowed
3. You don't need to have the passwords of every user to access anybodies phone number; try to impersonate your JBoss app with a single account specifically setup for you web app, having just enough rights to read what you need
4. Before doing any LDAP programming use a good LDAP editor to see whether you can gain access to the things you need. Try e.g. http://directory.apache.org/studio.

Comment: But how come it is possible to access in asp.net web application? are there any difference between C+ in asp.net and java? or objects used in asp.net and objects used in java? I asked the .net developer in my company with the source codes, it seems it is possible to get employee data from active directory without using server binding (by using userid and password). So I am wondering there may have a similar way as they used in .net. any ideas?

Comment: Are the clients using IE as the browser? Because the IE may pass a security token to the IIS hosting the ASP.NET app (in a specific MS way). If the DC trusts the IIS it may grant special rights. This is a kind of "auto-login" you may achieve with Kerberos, too (lots of work). Go with 3) and let the JBoss-App log into the AD and ask for any information needed. Phone numbers are usually not a big secret in "an intranet sense".

Comment: Yes, we are using IE10 with windows 7 in our company, No sure if I understand what you saying, does that mean the asp.net web apps with IIS can access Active Directory without any problem? if that is the case, .net and java do have different in access AD, My java web application is using JBoss 5 with Seam and Hibernate. could you please be more detailed of how to get phone# by using"JBoss-App log into the AD and ask for any information needed?". thanks a lot,